# Can we claim that all the terms in a matrix are less than equal to 1 if spectral radius is less than 1?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I have a a full column rank matrix A, and using this I want to construct a matrix with spectral radius less than 1. I do that using,

H = $I-\alpha A^{T} A$ ($I$ is identity matrix), where the term $\alpha$ is defined as, $\alpha = \frac{2}{trace(A^{T} A)}$.

Can I claim that each one of therm in my matrix H will be less than or equal to 1?

I believe that the solution is yes, since I have not been able to come up with the a single scenario where this claim is not true. But I am not able to prove this.

Comment: Your accepted answer is incorrect, by the way.  Cameron pointed out the flaw.

Comment: @JoshKeneda It isn't. The question is not about the entries of $A$, but about the entries of a matrix $H$ that is constructed from $A$. The accepted answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ah. Good catch. I do wish that the accepted answer mentioned how crucial the normality of $H$ is in the argument, though. The title of the question seems misleading, since the key property was the norm bound on $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

> **Claim:** $\|B\| \leq 1 \implies |B_{ij}| \leq 1$.

**Proof:** Note that
$$
|B_{ij}| = |e_i^TBe_j| = \|e_i^TBe_j\| \leq \|e_i^T\| \, \|Be_j\| \leq 
\|e_i^T\|\,\|B\|\, \|e_j\| \leq (1)(1)(1) = 1
$$

Comment: I am sorry for the redundant question but what is $e^{T}_{i}$ and $e_{j}$?

Comment: @RS $e_i$ is the (column) vector given by
$$
e_i = (\overbrace{0,\dots,0}^{i-1},1,0,\dots,0)
$$

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but you used $\|B\|\le 1$, not $\rho(B)\le 1$. If $\|B\|\le\rho(B)$, this would hold, but instead the opposite inequality holds.

Comment: @CameronWilliams but $B$ is symmetric, so the two are the same. In general, we always have $\rho(B)\leq \|B\|$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: your proof is wrong. Try to apply it to Fnacool's matrix with $i=1,j=2$.3 If you use that $B $ is selfadjoint,  you should say so.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I see no flaws in this answer. The OP is about their $H$, not $A$. By construction, unless $A$ is non-real, $H$ is a real symmetric matrix with spectral norm (= spectral radius as $H$ is real symmetric) $\le1$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I see no flaws in this answer. The OP is about their $H$, not $A$. By construction, unless $A$ is non-real, $H$ is a real symmetric matrix with spectral norm (= spectral radius as $H$ is real symmetric) $\le1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$A= \left(\begin{array}{cc} \frac 12 & 100 \\ 0 & \frac 12\end{array}\right),$$

It is upper diagonal, so eigenvalues are the diagonal elements. Spectral radius is $\frac 12$.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The OP is not about $A$, but about $H=I-\frac{2A^TA}{\operatorname{tr}(A^TA)}$.